# Cordova does not find ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using Apache Cordova and I'm trying to execute `sudo cordova build` command, but I'm getting the following error:

```
    Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

However, I've already set ANDROID_HOME, JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables on my .bashrc file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try executing the export statements with sudo too?

Comment: No, but my environment variables are already set. If I execute "echo $ANDROID_HOME" on the terminal, it gives me the path from my android sdk folder.. The problem is that cordova keeps failing to find ANDROID_HOME